# Problems defining relationships on automap

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the SQLA ORM AutomapBase functionality and finding some problems with the relationships. The database is Postgres managed by Odoo.

I found that there are 3 separate foreign keys declared on a table called `sale_order`:

- `partner_id`
- `partner_shipping_id`
- `partner_invoice_id`

They all point to the same table, `res_partner`. But when relying on the default relationship mapper any one of them can end up under the relationship `res_partner`, so I want to define the mapping myself so that they each get their own relationship. I tried to do this like so:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.relationships import RelationshipProperty

from app import odb


def name_for_scalar_relationship(base, local_cls, referred_cls, constraint):
    """Deals with a naming conflict problem."""
    name = referred_cls.__name__.lower()
    local_table = local_cls.__table__
    if name in local_table.columns:
        newname = name + "_"
        return newname
    return name


Base = automap_base()
tables = ['res_users', 'sale_order', 'res_partner', 'res_website']


class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sale_order'
    partner_invoice = relationship('res_partner',
                                   foreign_keys='res_user.id',
                                   primaryjoin='sale_order.partner_invoice_id==res_partner.id')
    partner_shipping = relationship('res_partner',
                                    foreign_keys='res_partner.id',
                                    primaryjoin='sale_order.partner_shipping_id==res_partner.id')
    partner = relationship('res_partner', foreign_keys='res_partner.id',
                           primaryjoin='sale_order.partner_id==res_partner.id')


Base.prepare(autoload_with=odb, reflection_options={'only': tables},
             name_for_scalar_relationship=name_for_scalar_relationship)

OUser = Base.classes.res_users
Partner = Base.classes.res_partner
Website = Base.classes.res_website

Session = sessionmaker(odb)
```

The problem is that this code produces the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5fe105d065d4> in <module>
      1 from app.omodels import *
      2 s = Session()
----> 3 o = s.query(Order).first()

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py in query(self, *entities, **kwargs)
   2104         """
   2105
-> 2106         return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
   2107
   2108     def _identity_lookup(

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py in __init__(self, entities, session)
    176
    177         self.session = session
--> 178         self._set_entities(entities)
    179
    180     def _set_propagate_attrs(self, values):

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py in _set_entities(self, entities)
    190                 post_inspect=True,
    191             )
--> 192             for ent in util.to_list(entities)
    193         ]
    194

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py in expect(role, element, apply_propagate_attrs, argname, post_inspect, **kw)
    177                     if insp is not None:
    178                         if post_inspect:
--> 179                             insp._post_inspect
    180                         try:
    181                             resolved = insp.__clause_element__()

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
   1178             if obj is None:
   1179                 return self
-> 1180             obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
   1181             obj._memoized_keys |= {self.__name__}
   1182             return result

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py in _post_inspect(self)
   2094
   2095         """
-> 2096         self._check_configure()
   2097
   2098     @HasMemoized.memoized_attribute

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py in _check_configure(self)
   1871     def _check_configure(self):
   1872         if self.registry._new_mappers:
-> 1873             _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
   1874
   1875     def _post_configure_properties(self):

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py in _configure_registries(registries, cascade)
   3382             # the order of mapper compilation
   3383
-> 3384             _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
   3385         finally:
   3386             _already_compiling = False

~/pe/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py in _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
   3417                 )
   3418                 e._configure_failed = mapper._configure_failed
-> 3419                 raise e
   3420
   3421             if not mapper.configured:

InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Order->sale_order'. Original exception was: 'Table' object has no attribute 'partner_invoice_id'
```

I've inspected the database and this column definitely does exist. I have no idea why it doesn't recognize the column. I even tried dropping into ipdb and the mapper->table seems to have this exact attribute.

It seems to me that it's trying to map the relationship before the reflection happens, but that doesn't really make sense to me. The docs specifically say to declare the table before calling `Base.prepare`.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**: It seems I'm misunderstanding something. The error is happening when I query, not when the schema is reflected. The column exists on the Order object's mapper. It's not finding the table for *that* Column, but this *still* doesn't make any sense to me. It looks identical to every other column, including foreign keys generated by reflection:

```
[ins] In [18]: cols['partner_invoice_id']
Out[18]: Column('partner_invoice_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('res_partner.id'), table=<sale_order>, nullable=False, comment='Invoice Address')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```py
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sale_order'
    partner_invoice = relationship('res_partner',
                                   foreign_keys='res_partner.id',
                                   primaryjoin='Order.partner_invoice_id==res_partner.id')
    partner_shipping = relationship('res_partner',
                                    foreign_keys='res_partner.id',
                                    primaryjoin='Order.partner_shipping_id==res_partner.id')
    partner = relationship('res_partner', foreign_keys='res_partner.id',
                           primaryjoin='Order.partner_id==res_partner.id')
```

The changes I made were:

- in `partner_invoice`, the table should be `res_partner`
- in all: the `sale_order` side of the `primaryjoin` attribute needs to be either `Model.attribute` or `table.c.column_name` to work - that's what's causing the `AttributeError`.

Note that running the code causes two warnings to be emitted:

> so68366814.py:43: SAWarning: relationship 'Order.partner_shipping'
> will copy column sale_order.partner_shipping_id to column
> res_partner.id, which conflicts with relationship(s):
> 'Order.partner_invoice' (copies sale_order.partner_invoice_id to
> res_partner.id). If this is not the intention, consider if these
> relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if
> viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only.
> For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially
> overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the
> columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add
> the parameter 'overlaps="partner_invoice"' to the
> 'Order.partner_shipping' relationship.
> o = s.query(Order).first()
>
> so68366814.py:43: SAWarning: relationship 'Order.partner' will copy
> column sale_order.partner_id to column res_partner.id, which conflicts
> with relationship(s): 'Order.partner_invoice' (copies
> sale_order.partner_invoice_id to res_partner.id),
> 'Order.partner_shipping' (copies sale_order.partner_shipping_id to
> res_partner.id). If this is not the intention, consider if these
> relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if
> viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only.
> For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially
> overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the
> columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add
> the parameter 'overlaps="partner_invoice,partner_shipping"' to the
> 'Order.partner' relationship.
> o = s.query(Order).first()

Based on the information [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#relationship-x-will-copy-column-q-to-column-p-which-conflicts-with-relationship-s-y), I *think* you can ignore the warnings:SQLAlchemy is telling you that it cannot determine how updates will work so you must rely on Odoo to handle them correctly.